# boost::asio::async_write write ssl::stream succuess but server not get

Tags: c++, ssl, asynchronous, boost-asio

I code a ssl server and client run a pingpang process, after a little time, client say send data success but server not get it.
client run in multi thread, when single thread, seem normal.
and i try add timer to add shake hand, then server can get all data, but i want it can run rightly with out shake hand
can anyone help figure out whats wrong.

here is my server

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
public:
    session(tcp::socket socket, boost::asio::ssl::context &context)
        : socket_(std::move(socket), context), m_strand(socket.get_executor()) {
    }

    void start() {
        do_handshake();
    }

private:
    void do_handshake() {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        socket_.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::server,
                                [this, self](const boost::system::error_code &error) {
                                    if (!error) {
                                        do_read();
                                    }
                                });
    }

    void do_read() {
        auto self(shared_from_this());

        socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_),
                                [this, self](const boost::system::error_code &ec, std::size_t length) {
                                    if (!ec) {
                                        std::cout << "get <";
                                        std::cout.write(data_, length);
                                        std::cout << std::endl;
                                        do_write(length);
                                    }
                                });
    }

    void do_write(std::size_t length) {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        std::cout << "send <";
        std::cout.write(data_, length);
        std::cout << std::endl;
        boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data_, length),
                                 [this, self](const boost::system::error_code &ec,
                                              std::size_t /*length*/) {
                                     if (!ec) {
                                         do_read();
                                     }
                                 });
    }

    boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket> socket_;
    boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::executor_type> m_strand;
    char data_[1024];
};

class server {
public:
    server(boost::asio::io_context &io_context, unsigned short port)
        : acceptor_(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)),
          context_(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23) {
        context_.set_options(
            boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds
            | boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2
            | boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
        context_.set_password_callback(std::bind(&server::get_password, this));
        context_.use_certificate_chain_file("server.pem");
        context_.use_private_key_file("server.pem", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
        context_.use_tmp_dh_file("dh2048.pem");

        do_accept();
    }

private:
    std::string get_password() const {
        return "test";
    }

    void do_accept() {
        acceptor_.async_accept(
            [this](const boost::system::error_code &error, tcp::socket socket) {
                if (!error) {
                    std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket), context_)->start();
                }

                do_accept();
            });
    }

    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    boost::asio::ssl::context context_;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    try {
        if (argc != 2) {
            std::cerr << "Usage: server <port>\n";
            return 1;
        }

        boost::asio::io_context io_context;

        using namespace std; // For atoi.
        server s(io_context, atoi(argv[1]));

        io_context.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and next client

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using std::placeholders::_1;
using std::placeholders::_2;

enum {
    max_length = 1024
};

class client {
public:
    client(boost::asio::io_context &io_context,
           boost::asio::ssl::context &context,
           const tcp::resolver::results_type &endpoints)
        : socket_(io_context, context), strand_(io_context.get_executor()) {
        socket_.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer);
        socket_.set_verify_callback(
            std::bind(&client::verify_certificate, this, _1, _2));

        connect(endpoints);
    }

private:
    bool verify_certificate(bool preverified,
                            boost::asio::ssl::verify_context &ctx) {
        char subject_name[256];
        X509 *cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
        X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);
        std::cout << "Verifying " << subject_name << "\n";

        return true;
    }

    void connect(const tcp::resolver::results_type &endpoints) {
        boost::asio::async_connect(socket_.lowest_layer(), endpoints,
                                   [this](const boost::system::error_code &error,
                                          const tcp::endpoint & /*endpoint*/) {
                                       if (!error) {
                                           handshake();
                                       } else {
                                           std::cout << "Connect failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
                                       }
                                   });
    }

    void handshake() {
        socket_.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client,
                                [this](const boost::system::error_code &error) {
                                    if (!error) {
                                        send_request("hello ssl");
                                        boost::asio::post(strand_, std::bind(&client::recv, this));
                                    } else {
                                        std::cout << "Handshake failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
                                    }
                                });
    }

    void send_request(const std::string &msg) {
        boost::asio::async_write(
            socket_, boost::asio::buffer(msg),
            [this](const boost::system::error_code &error, std::size_t length) {
                if (!error) {
                    std::cout << "send data success, size : " << length << std::endl;
                } else {
                    std::cout << "Write failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
                }
            });
    }

    void recv() {
        boost::asio::async_read(
            socket_, buffer_, boost::asio::transfer_exactly(9),
            boost::asio::bind_executor(
                strand_, [this](const boost::system::error_code &error, std::size_t length) {
                    if (!error) {
                        std::istream buffer(&buffer_);
                        std::vector<char> msg(length, 0);
                        buffer.readsome(msg.data(), length);
                        std::string recvMsg(msg.begin(), msg.end());
                        std::cout << recvMsg << std::endl;
                        send_request(recvMsg);
                        boost::asio::post(strand_, std::bind(&client::recv, this));
                    } else {
                        std::cout << "Read failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
                    }
                }));
    }

    boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket> socket_;
    boost::asio::streambuf buffer_;
    boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> strand_;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    try {
        if (argc != 3) {
            std::cerr << "Usage: client <host> <port>\n";
            return 1;
        }

        boost::asio::io_context io_context;

        tcp::resolver resolver(io_context);
        auto endpoints = resolver.resolve(argv[1], argv[2]);

        boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
        ctx.load_verify_file("ca.pem");

        client c(io_context, ctx, endpoints);
        boost::thread_group threadPool;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < boost::thread::hardware_concurrency(); ++i) {
            threadPool.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_context::run, &io_context));
        }
        io_context.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

when data not send to server,client will print like this

```
hello ssl
hello ssl
send data success, size : 9
send data success, size : 9
```

Comment: most part of code is from boost example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out. If you remove the thread_group (as far as I can tell, it adds no value), everything works. This is a good sign that you have a threading bug.

I'm not in the mood to read the code until I see the problem, so let's circle a bit.

Adding ASAN/UBSAN shows nothing bad immediately, so that's good.

Let me look at the code a little then.

- `session` creates a `m_strand` - which is never used...
- you forgot to join the extra threads

Now that I noticed some potential confusion around the strand, I looked at the client strand use. And see that it is inconsistent:

- the socket itself is NOT on the strand
- `send_request` doesn't run on *nor* bind the completion handler to the strand's executor
- the communication is full-duplex (meaning `async_write` and `async_read` happen concurrently).
- this means that where `client::recv` is posted to the strand, it doesn't actually synchronize threaded access to `socket_` (because the `send_request` is not tied to the strand in the first place)

> If the above is surprising, you're not the first to fall into that:
> [Why is `net::dispatch` needed when the I/O object already has an executor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68779959/why-is-netdispatch-needed-when-the-i-o-object-already-has-an-executor/68782989#68782989). In your example `connect()` and `handshake()` can be considered safe because they form a logical strand (sequential flow of execution). The problem arises with the concurrent paths.

By far the simplest way to fix the situation seems to construct `socket_` from the `strand_`. This implies reordering the members so `strand_` is initialized first:

```
client(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, ssl::context& context,
       const tcp::resolver::results_type& endpoints)
    : strand_(io_context.get_executor())
    , socket_(strand_, context)
```

Next up, all `post`s to the strand can be dropped because they always happen from a completion handler on that strand.

```
send_request("hello ssl");
recv(); // already on the strand in this completion handler
```

The mild irony is that `send_request` was executed under the implied assumption that it was on the strand.

The cleaned up programs until this point are

- File `client.cpp`

  ```
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   #include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
   #include <boost/thread.hpp>
   #include <cstdlib>
   #include <cstring>
   #include <functional>
   #include <iostream>

   using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
   using boost::system::error_code;
   using std::placeholders::_1;
   using std::placeholders::_2;
   namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;

   class client {
     public:
       client(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, ssl::context& context,
              const tcp::resolver::results_type& endpoints)
           : strand_(io_context.get_executor())
           , socket_(strand_, context)
       {
           socket_.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer);
           socket_.set_verify_callback(
               std::bind(&client::verify_certificate, this, _1, _2));

           connect(endpoints);
       }

     private:
       bool verify_certificate(bool preverified, ssl::verify_context& ctx)
       {
           char  subject_name[256];
           X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
           X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);
           std::cout << "Verifying " << subject_name << "\n";

           return true;
       }

       void connect(const tcp::resolver::results_type& endpoints)
       {
           async_connect( //
               socket_.lowest_layer(), endpoints,
               bind_executor(
                   strand_, [this](error_code error, const tcp::endpoint&) {
                       if (!error) {
                           handshake();
                       } else {
                           std::cout << "Connect failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
                       }
                   }));
       }

       void handshake()
       {
           socket_.async_handshake(
               ssl::stream_base::client,
               bind_executor(strand_, [this](error_code error) {
                   if (!error) {
                       send_request("hello ssl");
                       recv(); // already on the strand in this completion handler
                   } else {
                       std::cout << "Handshake failed: " << error.message()
                                 << "\n";
                   }
               }));
       }

       void send_request(std::string const& msg)
       {
           msg_ = msg;
           async_write(
               socket_, boost::asio::buffer(msg_),
               bind_executor(
                   strand_, [/*this*/](error_code error, std::size_t length) {
                       if (!error) {
                           std::cout << "send data success, size : " << length << std::endl;
                       } else {
                           std::cout << "Write failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
                       }
                   }));
       }

       void recv()
       {
           async_read(
               socket_, buffer_, boost::asio::transfer_exactly(9),
               boost::asio::bind_executor(
                   strand_, [this](error_code error, std::size_t length) {
                       if (!error) {
                           std::istream      buffer(&buffer_);
                           std::vector<char> msg(length, 0);
                           buffer.readsome(msg.data(), length);

                           msg_.assign(msg.begin(), msg.end());
                           std::cout << msg_ << std::endl;

                           send_request(msg_);
                           recv(); // already on the strand in this completion handler
                       } else {
                           std::cout << "Read failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
                       }
                   }));
       }

       boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> strand_;
       ssl::stream<tcp::socket>                                    socket_;
       boost::asio::streambuf                                      buffer_;
       std::string                                                 msg_;
   };

   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   {
       try {
           if (argc != 3) {
               std::cerr << "Usage: client <host> <port>\n";
               return 1;
           }

           boost::asio::io_context io_context;

           tcp::resolver resolver(io_context);
           auto          endpoints = resolver.resolve(argv[1], argv[2]);

           ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::sslv23);
           ctx.load_verify_file("ca.pem");

           client              c(io_context, ctx, endpoints);
           boost::thread_group threadPool;
           for (size_t i = 0; i < boost::thread::hardware_concurrency(); ++i) {
               threadPool.create_thread(
                   boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_context::run, &io_context));
           }
           threadPool.join_all();
           //io_context.run();

           return 0;
       } catch (std::exception const& e) {
           std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
           return 1;
       }
   }
  ```
- File `server.cpp`

  ```
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   #include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
   #include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
   #include <cstdlib>
   #include <functional>
   #include <iostream>

   namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;
   using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
   using boost::system::error_code;

   class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
     public:
       session(tcp::socket socket, ssl::context& context)
           : socket_(std::move(socket), context)
           , m_strand(socket.get_executor())
       {
       }

       void start()
       {
           do_handshake();
       }

     private:
       void do_handshake()
       {
           auto self(shared_from_this());
           socket_.async_handshake(ssl::stream_base::server,
                                   [this, self](error_code error) {
                                       if (!error) {
                                           do_read();
                                       }
                                   });
       }

       void do_read()
       {
           auto self(shared_from_this());

           socket_.async_read_some(
               boost::asio::buffer(data_),
               [this, self](error_code ec, std::size_t length) {
                   if (!ec) {
                       std::cout << "get <";
                       std::cout.write(data_, length);
                       std::cout << std::endl;
                       do_write(length);
                   }
               });
       }

       void do_write(std::size_t length)
       {
           auto self(shared_from_this());
           std::cout << "send <";
           std::cout.write(data_, length);
           std::cout << std::endl;
           boost::asio::async_write(
               socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data_, length),
               [this, self](error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/) {
                   if (!ec) {
                       do_read();
                   }
               });
       }

       ssl::stream<tcp::socket>                        socket_;
       boost::asio::strand<tcp::socket::executor_type> m_strand;
       char                                            data_[1024];
   };

   class server {
     public:
       server(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, unsigned short port)
           : acceptor_(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
           , context_(ssl::context::sslv23)
       {
           context_.set_options(ssl::context::default_workarounds |
                                ssl::context::no_sslv2 |
                                ssl::context::single_dh_use);
           context_.set_password_callback(std::bind(&server::get_password, this));
           context_.use_certificate_chain_file("server.pem");
           context_.use_private_key_file("server.pem", ssl::context::pem);
           context_.use_tmp_dh_file("dh2048.pem");

           do_accept();
       }

     private:
       std::string get_password() const
       {
           return "test";
       }

       void do_accept()
       {
           acceptor_.async_accept([this](error_code error, tcp::socket socket) {
               if (!error) {
                   std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket), context_)->start();
               }

               do_accept();
           });
       }

       tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
       ssl::context  context_;
   };

   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   {
       try {
           if (argc != 2) {
               std::cerr << "Usage: server <port>\n";
               return 1;
           }

           boost::asio::io_context io_context;

           server s(io_context, std::atoi(argv[1]));

           io_context.run();
           return 0;
       } catch (std::exception const& e) {
           std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
           return 1;
       }
   }
  ```

### Other Problems

### Lifetime Error

UBSAN/ASAN didn't catch it,but this is wrong:

```
void send_request(const std::string& msg)
{
    async_write(
        socket_, boost::asio::buffer(msg),
        ...
```

The problem is the lifetime of `msg`, which disappears before the async operation got a chance to run, let alone complete. So, move the buffer so the lifetime is sufficient (e.g. member `msg_`).

### Concurrent Writes

When the client locks up, it shows

```
send data success, size : 9
hello ssl
hello ssl
send data success, size : 9
send data success, size : 9
```

This indicates that a second `hello ssl` is received before send is initiated. This means that a second send is initiated. Under the hood this cancels a duplex synchronization object inside the ssl stream context. You can see this with `-DBOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING`:

```
@asio|1630155694.209267|51139|deadline_timer@0x7ffc6fa61e48.cancel
```

Visualizing with the `handlerviz.pl` script:

[image]

The problem is violating [the requirements here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload4.html#:%7E:text=The%20program%20must%20ensure%20that%20the%20stream%20performs%20no%20other%20write%20operations%20(such%20as%20async_write%2C%20the%20stream%27s%20async_write_some%20function%2C%20or%20any%20other%20composed%20operations%20that%20perform%20writes)%20until%20this%20operation%20completes):

> The program must ensure that the stream performs no other write operations (such as async_write, the stream's async_write_some function, or any other composed operations that perform writes) until this operation completes.

Two easy ways to fix it:

1. change the IO from full duplex to sequential read/write/read/write just like the server
2. make an output queue that contains messages still to be written in sequence

### Fixed Solution

This uses an outbox as in the second solution for overlapping writes above. I've also taken the liberty to

- remove the unnecessary intermediate buffer `streambuf buffer_` instead reading directly into a string.
- replace `io_context` + `thread_group` with the more elegant `thread_pool`
- many minor improvements (some mentioned above)

- File `client.cpp`

  ```
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   #include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
   #include <boost/thread.hpp>
   #include <cstdlib>
   #include <cstring>
   #include <functional>
   #include <iostream>

   using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
   using boost::system::error_code;
   using std::placeholders::_1;
   using std::placeholders::_2;
   namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;

   using Executor = boost::asio::thread_pool::executor_type;

   class client {
     public:
       client(Executor ex, ssl::context& context,
              const tcp::resolver::results_type& endpoints)
           : strand_(ex)
           , socket_(strand_, context)
       {
           socket_.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer);
           socket_.set_verify_callback(
               std::bind(&client::verify_certificate, this, _1, _2));

           connect(endpoints);
       }

     private:
       bool verify_certificate(bool preverified, ssl::verify_context& ctx)
       {
           char  subject_name[256];
           X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
           X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);
           std::cout << "Verifying " << subject_name << "\n";

           return true;
       }

       void connect(const tcp::resolver::results_type& endpoints)
       {
           async_connect( //
               socket_.lowest_layer(), endpoints,
               bind_executor(
                   strand_, [this](error_code error, const tcp::endpoint&) {
                       if (!error) {
                           handshake();
                       } else {
                           std::cout << "Connect failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
                       }
                   }));
       }

       void handshake()
       {
           socket_.async_handshake(
               ssl::stream_base::client,
               bind_executor(strand_, [this](error_code error) {
                   if (!error) {
                       send_request("hello ssl");
                       recv(); // already on the strand in this completion handler
                   } else {
                       std::cout << "Handshake failed: " << error.message()
                                 << "\n";
                   }
               }));
       }

       void send_request(std::string msg)
       {
           outbox_.push_back(std::move(msg));
           if (outbox_.size() == 1)
           {
               send_loop();
           }
       }

       void send_loop()
       {
           async_write( //
               socket_, boost::asio::buffer(outbox_.back()),
               bind_executor(
                   strand_, [this](error_code error, std::size_t length) {
                       if (!error) {
                           std::cout << "send data success, size : " << length << std::endl;
                           outbox_.pop_back();
                       } else {
                           std::cout << "Write failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
                       }
                       if (!outbox_.empty())
                           send_loop();
                   }));
       }

       void recv()
       {
           async_read(
               socket_, boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(buffer_), boost::asio::transfer_exactly(9),
               boost::asio::bind_executor(
                   strand_, [this](error_code error, std::size_t length) {
                       if (!error) {
                           std::cout << buffer_ << std::endl;

                           send_request(std::move(buffer_));
                           recv(); // already on the strand in this completion handler
                       } else {
                           std::cout << "Read failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
                       }
                   }));
       }

       boost::asio::strand<Executor> strand_;
       ssl::stream<tcp::socket>      socket_;
       std::string                   buffer_;
       std::deque<std::string>       outbox_;
   };

   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   {
       try {
           if (argc != 3) {
               std::cerr << "Usage: client <host> <port>\n";
               return 1;
           }

           ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::sslv23);
           ctx.load_verify_file("ca.pem");

           boost::asio::thread_pool io;
           tcp::resolver resolver(io);

           client c(io.get_executor(), ctx, resolver.resolve(argv[1], argv[2]));
           io.join();

           return 0;
       } catch (std::exception const& e) {
           std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
           return 1;
       }
   }
  ```
- File `server.cpp`

  ```
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   #include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
   #include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
   #include <cstdlib>
   #include <functional>
   #include <iostream>

   namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;
   using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
   using boost::system::error_code;

   class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
     public:
       session(tcp::socket socket, ssl::context& context)
           : socket_(std::move(socket), context)
       {
       }

       void start()
       {
           do_handshake();
       }

     private:
       void do_handshake()
       {
           auto self(shared_from_this());
           socket_.async_handshake(ssl::stream_base::server,
                                   [this, self](error_code error) {
                                       if (!error) {
                                           do_read();
                                       }
                                   });
       }

       void do_read()
       {
           auto self(shared_from_this());

           socket_.async_read_some(
               boost::asio::buffer(data_),
               [this, self](error_code ec, std::size_t length) {
                   if (!ec) {
                       std::cout << "get <";
                       std::cout.write(data_.data(), length);
                       std::cout << std::endl;
                       do_write(length);
                   }
               });
       }

       void do_write(std::size_t length)
       {
           auto self(shared_from_this());
           std::cout << "send <";
           std::cout.write(data_.data(), length);
           std::cout << std::endl;
           boost::asio::async_write(
               socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data_.data(), length),
               [this, self](error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/) {
                   if (!ec) {
                       do_read();
                   }
               });
       }

       ssl::stream<tcp::socket> socket_;
       std::array<char, 1024>   data_;
   };

   class server {
     public:
       server(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, unsigned short port)
           : acceptor_(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
           , context_(ssl::context::sslv23)
       {
           context_.set_options(ssl::context::default_workarounds |
                                ssl::context::no_sslv2 |
                                ssl::context::single_dh_use);
           context_.set_password_callback(std::bind(&server::get_password, this));
           context_.use_certificate_chain_file("server.pem");
           context_.use_private_key_file("server.pem", ssl::context::pem);
           context_.use_tmp_dh_file("dh2048.pem");

           do_accept();
       }

     private:
       std::string get_password() const
       {
           return "test";
       }

       void do_accept()
       {
           acceptor_.async_accept([this](error_code error, tcp::socket socket) {
               if (!error) {
                   std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket), context_)->start();
               }

               do_accept();
           });
       }

       tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
       ssl::context  context_;
   };

   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   {
       try {
           if (argc != 2) {
               std::cerr << "Usage: server <port>\n";
               return 1;
           }

           boost::asio::io_context io_context;

           server s(io_context, std::atoi(argv[1]));

           io_context.run();
           return 0;
       } catch (std::exception const& e) {
           std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
           return 1;
       }
   }
  ```

Live Demo:

[image]

As you can see (using a `uniq -dc` trick to suppress all non-repeating lines) now it happily continues in the case where multiple receives come in before send is initiated.

Comment: Note this is a long read. Be sure to reach the end because the problems uncovered the second half are important.

Comment: either the solution or process of analysis is very helpful, thx